# how to search for a specific nouns in a PDF file inside an XML file and print the noun and its root as an output

Tags: python, xml, csv, pdf, artificial-intelligence

I have a code that is going to extract the nouns from a specific line in a PDF file and then save the outputs in another file, then I made an XML file that contains some of these nouns inside a root and different child roots, now I'm trying to write a code to search for the same nouns in the PDF inside the XML file then print the noun and the child root that it is inspired in

the code:

```
! pip install -U textblob
! python -m textblob.download_corpora
! pip install pdfplumber

# Import required library.
import pdfplumber
from textblob import TextBlob

# Open the file and create a pdf object.
pdf = pdfplumber.open("Sample_Medical_Report.pdf")
# Get the number of pages.
numPages = len(pdf.pages)
# Iterate over each page, Extract the text of each page and save it into text file.
for number, pageText in enumerate(pdf.pages):
 with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
  print(pageText.extract_text(), file=f)

# to extract blocks of text of a file that starts with "Diagnosis" until it encounters another "Diagnosis".
buff = []
i = 1
with open('output.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("Diagnosis"):
            # write a file only if buff isn't empty.  (if it is 
            # empty, this must be the very first header, so we
            # don't need to write an output file yet)
            if buff:
                output = open('file' + '%d.txt' % i, 'w')
                output.write(''.join(buff))
                output.close()
                i += 1
                buff = []  # buffer reset
        if line.strip():
            buff.append(line)

# write the final section
if buff:
    output = open('file' + '%d.txt' % i, 'w')
    output.write(''.join(buff))
    output.close()

# extracting the nouns from the new text file
blob = TextBlob (open("file2.txt").read())
for nouns in blob.noun_phrases:
   with open('output1.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(nouns + '\n')
```

I have tried to use a code but it didn't give me the correct output that I was expected

the code:

```
import xml.tree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

# Load the XML file
tree = ET.parse('hospital.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Load the list of nouns
with open('output1.txt', 'r') as f:
    nouns = f.read().splitlines()

# Create a CSV file to store the output
with open('file_name.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    # Iterate over the nouns
    for noun in nouns:
        # Find the child root that contains the noun
        child_root = root.find(f'disease[@name="{noun}"]')

        # If the child root is found, get the clinic name
        if child_root is not None:
            clinic_name = child_root.find('clinic').text
        # Otherwise, set the clinic name to None
        else:
            clinic_name = None

        # Write the noun and clinic name to the CSV file
        writer.writerow([noun, clinic_name])
```

Comment: Please [edit] post with a sample of relevant XML for [mre] if PDF extraction works. Redact as necessary.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What output do you expect and what is your input?